# Delete in a secure way MBR from Mac formatted external drive (APM)

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, mbr

I was trying to restore my old external hard drive (Disk 1) with mac files (APM), but when I connected it to windows I accidentally added a MBR boot partition. I do not currently own a Mac computer.

This is how the properties of the disk I want to access look like:

[image]

When I try to access the files using the [HFSexplorer software](https://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/), I click on File>load file system and when I choose the disk (disk1) I get the following error:

[image]

[image]

I would like to know if someone can tell me what steps I should follow to safely remove the MBR from that disk and only leave the APM so that I can see the files on the disk from Windows.

Is there any way to remove that boot record from the disk without affecting the files on the disk or damaging the other APM boot system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try [Paragon HFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/). The free trial might be sufficient to get you out of this.

I'm suspicious of HFSExplorer discovering an APM formatted drive. Apple hasn't used APM since the very beginning of OS X, 20 years ago. They use GUID [known as GPT to Windows users].

Answer (score 1):

Pick a linux distro. You may be able to recover your files outright through mounting individual partitions. Failing that `testdisk` will restore good partition layout and re-write the MBR (not sure if it will work with APM)

In future it pays not to mix-n-match anything non-windows, with windows, cos windows doesn't play nicely with others.